# psycopg2 throws unterminated dollar-quoted string error at or near "$body$"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, alembic

I'm trying to build an alembic migration revision to create a User Defined Function in PostgreSQL server version 10.2, however the script keeps throwing an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$body$
                select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'), '"
    LINE 6:         as $body$
                       ^
     [SQL: "\n        create or replace function naturalsort(text)\n          returns bytea\n          language sql\n          immutable strict\n        as $body$ \n            select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'), '\x00') from regexp_matches($1, '0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)', 'g') r; \n        $body$;\n    "] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

The script I'm running:

```
def upgrade():
    conn = op.get_bind()

    conn.execute('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "naturalsort"')

    conn.execute("""
        create or replace function naturalsort(text)
          returns bytea
          language sql
          immutable strict
        as $body$ 
            select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'), '\x00') from regexp_matches($1, '0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)', 'g') r; 
        $body$;
    """)
```

The code should allow for natural sorting columns and is a copy/paste from [rhodium toad](http://www.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/junk/naturalsort.sql).

As dollar-quoted strings are a way to re-write string constants, the alternative would be (note the double single-quotes as per the postgresql documentation: "To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes, e.g., 'Dianne''s horse'. Note that this is not the same as a double-quote character (")."):

```
conn.execute("""
    create or replace function naturalsort(text)
      returns bytea
      language sql
      immutable strict
    as 'select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), ''SQL_ASCII''), ''\x00'') from regexp_matches($1, ''0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)'', ''g'') r;';
""")
```

however this throws a similar error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) unterminated quoted string at or near "'select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), ''SQL_ASCII''), ''"
LINE 6:         as 'select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], leng...
                   ^
 [SQL: "\n        create or replace function naturalsort(text)\n          returns bytea\n          language sql\n          immutable strict\n        as 'select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), ''SQL_ASCII''), ''\x00'') from regexp_matches($1, ''0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)'', ''g'') r;';\n    "] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Strange thing is that these queries execute fine in pgAdmin and alembic seems to generate valid SQL (alembic upgrade : --sql):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "naturalsort";

create or replace function naturalsort(text)
          returns bytea
          language sql
          immutable strict
        as $body$
            select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'), '') from regexp_matches($1, '0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)', 'g') r;
        $body$;;

UPDATE alembic_version SET version_num='ad99fdcb28bc' WHERE alembic_version.version_num = 'ff00ac684617';

COMMIT;
```

Any clues to why psycopg2 keeps throwing the `unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$body$` error?

Comment: you might want to try passing `$body$` as a string argument to the `execute` method instead of having in the query itself.

Comment: @moshevi, thanks for responding. You mean like this?:

    `conn.execute("""
        create or replace function naturalsort(text)
          returns bytea
          language sql
          immutable strict
        as %s;
    """ % "$body$ select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'), '\x00') from regexp_matches($1, '0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)', 'g') r; $body$")`

Running this still gives me the same error (`unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$body$`) unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "naturalsort"')

    op.execute("""
      create or replace function naturalsort(text)
      returns bytea
      language sql
      immutable strict
    as $my_body$
        select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'), '') from regexp_matches($1, '0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)', 'g') r;
    $my_body$;;
    """)


def downgrade():
    op.execute('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "naturalsort"')
```

When executing the upgrade it succeeds without an error about syntax.
Actually executing the function in postgres also gives back the desired naturalsort result using this query:

`SELECT * FROM public.requirement ORDER BY naturalsort(eid) asc`

Using [PvdL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512238/pvdl)s comment about `my_body` worked partially, it will throw a syntax error if I add `'\x00'` where the empty string is now (after `SQL_ASCII`)

Answer (score 1):

`$body` is an alias which can not contain $, replace `$body$` with a name like `my_body` and it should work

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "some_tag"
LINE 6:         as some_tag select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r...`

We're making use of dollar quoted string constants to circumvent the use of quotes in the inner SQL query. It is described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/sql-syntax-lexical.html) in §4.1.2.4.